# OpenCV Environment variable changed

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I had my standalone installation of OpenCV on my Linux machine and it was running OK. I installed ROS (comes with its OpenCV) and today I cannot run my CMakeLists.txt in any of my OpenCV projects, getting the error of :

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I am kinda sure this happened because some environment variable got changed however I don't know where to look at.

Could someone walk me through this?

Comment: So, what happens if you follow the instructions in the last paragraph?

Comment: Well, I reinstalled OpenCV and it worked, probably changed the environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling OpenCV solved the problem for me, since it re-modified the Environment variable.